# Avoid using flags to control invocation of code

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I am new to ReactiveCocoa and trying to understand , how I can model the following example using reactive cocoa commands: I am trying to read bytes from stream and this is done in the function "readStream". I want to prevent further calls to readStream , until I am done with the first batch of reading. As shown, I am using the "reading" flag, which is set when reading starts and is reset when reading is done. I would like to avoid using the flag "reading", can this be coded in a better way using reactive cocoa.

```
- (void) stream:(NSStream *) aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    ..
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    if (!self.reading){
        self.reading = YES; //
        [self readStream]; // Reads bytes from the stream
     }
     break;

 - (void) readStream {
       // Read data
      self.reading = NO;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

RACCommands enables button until the returned signal complete, I'm not sure the context with your code, if it locates in lower level global singleton component, you still need keep the flag.